# Which countries don't require employers to have a local entity to hire someone (not even an EOR)?

Tags: recruitment, international

Which countries don't require employers to have a local entity in order to hire software engineers locally? I know you can use an Employer of Record, but which countries don't even require that. I.e. the US LLC can directly enter into a contract with them and avoid the headaches they would otherwise face.

Comment: Worth remembering that in many countries, employees can be self-employed, and therefore the question becomes: Which countries allow their local companies to do business internationally?

Comment: Too broad. There are 180+ countries all with their own complicated set of rules and regulations and all with different definition of what "hiring' means.

Answer (score 1):

As an example: I live in the UK. If you want to hire me, then you need a company that is registered at companieshouse.gov.uk, which is responsible to pay my income tax, my employee national insurance, and its own employer national insurance to the tax office (HMRC).

However, I can start a limited company in the UK and do all these things myself, with me as my company's employee, and then my company and your company can sign a contract where your company pays my company money for doing work for you. We don't even need a written contract, as long as I do the work, and you pay.